# Javascript location.replace bug in Opera

Tags: javascript, location, opera

I'm am doing a JS location.replace in Opera. There is a known bug that the location does not get replaced but updated when only the location.hash changes (see http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=568931).

I was trying to do the following workaround:

```
var url = location.href.split("#")[0];
if (window.opera) {
  window.history.back();
}
location.replace(url + '#' + newhash);
```

Unfortunately that does not seem work. Before I start experimenting with setTimeout, I wanted to check if maybe someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best workaround for this is to not work around it at all.

Reasoning: firstly, the script running in *this* page should be terminated if I use the back button, or `history.back()` is called. Hence, in your workaround above the script will (or should) actually stop running before the `location.replace()` call. We can not remember that you wanted to call location.replace() and do it on the page you've gone back to, because that would be a script injection security issue.

Secondly, even if this workaround worked I would very much recommend not using it. The reason is that Opera will eventually fix its bug. If an end user used a *fixed* Opera version and a page running your script, each click on one of your links would remove one entry from that user's browsing history..

For a proper solution, you could investigate `history.replaceState()` - a new method specified in HTML5: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-history-replacestate

Comment: I absolutely agree on first and second.

history.replaceState() seems to be helpful and Opera fully supports it. I will investigate and report back here. 

Thank you!

Comment: I tried:
window.history.replaceState(window.history.state, "", url);
window.history.go(0);
Unfortunately this reloads the page (but the replace works!). Since I'm using the replace mainly to shorten long hashes, the replaceState is enough for me (I do not need the onhashchange event). Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify a bit? I took the example from the forum link you posted and uploaded it here: http://people.opera.com/miket/tmp/replace.html. In Opera 11.61/Mac, it appears to work as expected.

Are you seeing something different? Can you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: I'm testing in Opera 11.60/Windows 7. The problem is that in Opera the location just changes. It does not get replaced, e.g. when I click the button in FF, I can not use the undo function. In Opera I can. Is that different for you?

Comment: by "undo", do you mean "back"?

Comment: yes, the browser navigation "back". I was a bit unclear there.